# Display absolute div on top of div "grand-parent"

Tags: javascript, html, css

How to display a child element on top of his "grand-parent" container, knowing that the grand-parent is `overflow: auto`.

```css
.child {
  position: absolute;
  height: 200px;
  width: 150px;
  border: black solid 1px;
  background-color: pink;
  top: 10px;
  right: 0;
}

.parent {
  position: relative;
  height: 80px;
  border: black solid 1px;
  background-color: green;
}

.grand {
  position: relative;
  background-color: blue solid 2px;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: gray;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="grand">
  <div class="parent">
    <div class="child"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

How can I display the child container on top of parent and grand-parent (without changing the overflow property for the grand-parent)?

[Desired Outcome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wih40.png)

Answer (score 1):

It seems impossible to visible the `child` element while it's `grandparent`  has `overflow: auto` because of while trying to make the `grandparent` scrollable, the `child` becomes the
content of the `grandparent` 's scrollable area.

But it can be done if we wrap the `grandparent` with `grand-grand-parent` and position the child element on its respect.

Here is what I have done:

```css
.parent {
  height: 180px;
  border: black solid 1px;
  background-color: green;
}

.child {
  position: absolute;
  height: 200px;
  width: 150px;
  border: black solid 1px;
  background-color: pink;
  top:  32px;
  right: -24px;
}

.grand {
  height: 80px;
  background-color: gray;
  overflow:  auto;
}

.grand-grand-parent{
  position: relative;
  margin: 100px 100px;
```

```html
<div class="grand-grand-parent">
  <div class="grand">
      <div class="parent">
          <div class="child"></div>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Child positioning is relative to parent container .. so that's why I need it to be relative to the parent but It must be in foreground of grand-parent container

Comment: must be in foreground of grand-parent means?

Answer (score 0):

you can give to your grand parent `position: relative;` and to your grand-son - `position: absolute; bottom: -20px; right: -20px;`